# Thread error while running scheduled task inside of a Flask application

Tags: python, apscheduler

I want to create a scheduler that will run every hour in my Flask application. To do this, I use the APScheduler library. Here is the most basic source code I could find online:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import atexit

cron = Scheduler(daemon=True)
cron.start()

@cron.interval_schedule(minutes=1)
def job_function():
    print("Hi")

atexit.register(lambda: cron.shutdown(wait=False))
```

When I try to run my application, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dimitar/Desktop/dev/Tradiebot/local/WorxManager/backend/Server/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    def job_function():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 405, in inner
    func.job = self.add_interval_job(func, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 347, in add_interval_job
    return self.add_job(trigger, func, args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 285, in add_job
    if not self.running:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 148, in running
    thread_alive = self._thread and self._thread.isAlive()
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
```

After a bit of research, I found that other people on python 3.9 have experienced a similar issue, but I found no solution to the problem.

I do not want to downgrade my python version in fear that it will effect other libraries I am using as some of them are new and not developed to run on older versions of python.

Is there a  workaround or an alternative library I can use to schedule a task to run in specified time intervals on a flask application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks like it belongs to APScheduler 2.x which has not been updated in 7 years. Upgrade and the problem goes away.

Comment: Indeed, as I commented on @Shine's answer, I did have an issue with the version of the code snippet. I guess copying the first thing that comes up on Stack Overflow doesnt always solve the problem. After updating to the latest version and changin my code, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Python3.9 deprecated `Thread.isAlive`: [source](https://bugs.python.org/issue37804). So buckle up and tackle your fears because one of your dependencies (`apscheduler`) requires `<python39`.

To test this easily though I would use `virtualenv` with a specific version and see if the problem continues.

`virtualenv --python py38 myvenv`

For that command you'll need python38 available on your `$PATH`, e.g. install it on your machine. Then rerun your code.

Comment: Actually, the reason why I was getting an error is that I was trying to run legacy code. The code snipped I found to test the library was written years ago. I found a newer code snippet and after updating to the latest version of apscheduler, it works fine.